# Compare-Object gives false differences

Tags: powershell

I have some problem with Compare-Object. My task is to get difference 
between two directory snapshots made at different times. First 
snapshot is taken like this:

```
ls -recurse d:\dir | export-clixml dir-20100129.xml
```

Then, later, I get second snapshot and load both of them:

```
$b = (import-clixml dir-20100130.xml) 
$a = (import-clixml dir-20100129.xml)
```

Next, I'm trying to compare with Compare-Object, like that:

```
diff $a $b
```

What I get is in some places files that were added to $b since $a, but 
in some -- files that were in both snapshots, and some files, that 
were added to $b, are not given in Compare-Object output. Puzzling, 
but $b.count - $a.count is **EXACTLY** the same as (diff $a $b).count. Why 
is that?

Ok, Compare-Object has -property param. I try to use that:

```
diff -property fullname $a $b
```

And I get the whole mess of differences: it shows me **ALL** the files. 
For example, say $a contains:

```
A\1.txt 
A\2.txt 
A\3.txt
```

And $b contains:

```
X\2.mp3 
X\3.mp3 
X\4.mp3 
A\1.txt 
A\2.txt 
A\3.txt
```

diff output is something like that:

```
X\2.mp3 => 
A\1.txt <= 
X\3.mp3 => 
A\2.txt <= 
X\4.mp3 => 
A\3.txt <= 
A\1.txt => 
A\2.txt => 
A\3.txt =>
```

Weird. I think I don't understand something crucial about Compare- 
Object usage, and manuals are scarce... Please, help me to get the 
**DIFFERENCE** between two directory snapshots. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** I've saved data as plain strings like that:

```
> import-clixml dir-20100129.xml | % { $_.fullname } | out-file -enc utf8 a.txt
```

And results are the same. Here're excerpts of both snapshots (top 100-something lines, a.txt and b.txt), output of compare-object, and output of UNIX diff (unified). All files are UTF-8: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2873752/compare-object-problem.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can solve the problem by using -SyncWindow parameter. The value should be half a length of a smallest collection in comparison:

```
> Compare-Object -SyncWindow ($a.length / 2) $a $b
```

Source: http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/06/06/compare-object-gotcha/

Comment: Note that as of PowerShell v2, the `-SyncWindow` property has a default value of `[int32]::MaxValue`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the export-clixml/import-clixml. It actually changes the type of each file object from System.IO.FileSystemInfo to Deserialized.System.IO.FileInfo.

Have your second ls command export-clixml to a temporary file, then import and compare against that and it should fix the problem.

Comment: Actually, both snapshot are from Import-Clixml, sorry for misleading. I've corrected the question. But it has no effect, actually -- result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

A good example that I've found is this.

Get the original status for services:

```
$before = get-service
```

Now make some changes to the service, for example shut down 1 and start 1.

Get the new status for services:

```
$after = get-service
```

Then compare the two lists (diff is an alias for Compare-Object):

```
diff $before $after -property name,status
```

Examples results:

```
PS> diff $before $after -property name,status

name                                                                     status SideIndicator
----                                                                     ------ -------------
Spooler                                                                 Stopped =>
Spooler                                                                 Running <=
```

Demonstrates 1st object with the <=, 2nd object of the change seen with a =>.
Or simply a before and after perspective. You could also create a label and expression to show the word "Changed" in the event there is a =>.

Using this you can also see in a comparison when something is in the first list but was in the second. Much like a find unmatch query.

Comment: To further improve the answer, try using the same context (a directly list) to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i find that diff works better if you can sort it first

Try

```
$b = (import-clixml dir-20100130.xml) | sort
$a = (import-clixml dir-20100129.xml) | sort
diff $a $b
```

Comment: `get-alias diff` would show its actually just `Compare-Object`